# how to set up 'chromedriver.exe' executable in PATH on gitlab ci

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest, gitlab-ci

class Application(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Admin/365_python_test/chromedriver.exe')
```

this is my initialization of webdriver. It works fine on my machine, but when I push code to gitlab CI I get error 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. As I understand I must set up Path in .gitlab-ci.yml in 'before script' section but I don't know how to do it. I tried different script I found here but it doesn't work. I tried also:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

which doesn't work on CI as well:

```
 venv/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:111: WebDriverException
 ---------------------------- Captured stdout setup --------------------- 
 --------

 Checking for linux64 chromedriver:2.46 in cache
 There is no cached driver. Downloading new one...
 Trying to download new driver from 
 http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/chromedriver_linux64.zip
 Unpack archive /root/.wdm/chromedriver/2.46/linux64/chromedriver.zip
 =========================== 1 error in 1.30 seconds 
 ============================
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Help, please!

Comment: You have a hardcoded windows path passed to `executable`, it will work only on windows. However, you are obviously running the code in a Linux container, so the path won't be resolved. Remove the path, make sure `chromedriver` is available (either use a container with `chromedriver` preinstalled or install it yourself in `.gitlab-ci.yml`) and modify the `PATH` variable in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, section `before_script`: `- export PATH="path/to/chromedriver:${PATH}"`

Comment: Thanks, hoefling! I found one solution: image: joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:3.6 after changing chrome options everything is ok!